# How to append the checkbox with the children div of a main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a checkbox  with each children.
For that I used

```
var len = $("#personalDetails").children("div").length;
    for(var id=0; id<len;id++)
    {
       var el = $('<input type="checkbox"/>');
        $("#personalDetails").children(":first").attr("id",id);
        alert(id);
        $( "#"+id).append(el);       
    }
```

html

```
<div id="personalDetails">
    <div>personal</div>
    <div>Education</div>
</div>
```

By doing this I got a problem. All checkboxes are coming under one div. How can I set one for one div and other for other div?
[Note: We can not put any id or class for children div]
http://jsfiddle.net/QTzrB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#personalDetails > div').each(function(idx, el){
        $('<input type="checkbox"/>').attr("id", idx).appendTo(el);
    })
    $('#personalDetails').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cd2Kv/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var len = $("#personalDetails").children("div").length;
    $("#personalDetails div").each(function(idx) {
    $(this).append("<input type='checkbox' id="+ idx +" />");
});

$("input[type=checkbox]" ).on("click",function(){
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/QTzrB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
  $("#personalDetails").children("div").each(function(index, obj) {
     var $chk = $("<input/>",{"type":"checkbox"});
     $(this).prepend($chk.attr("id",index));                
     $chk.on("click",function(){
        alert(this.id);
     });
   });
});
```

Working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HNezs/

Answer (score 0):

replace your script with this one,hope this will do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#personalDetails').children('div').each(function(){
     $(this).append('<input type="checkbox"/>');
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFgqU/)

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the div list. Also if you don't want to put ids to the input elements then you can cache them also.

Below code is working on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTzrB/4/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("#personalDetails").children("div");
    var len = divs.length;

    for(var id = 0; id < len; id++) {
       var el = $('<input type="checkbox"/>');
       divs.eq(id).append(el);       
    }
});
```